# A matching problem for 3 decks of cards

Tags: probability, games

a recent posting on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/probability-of-card-decks-being-in-the-same-order-for-n-shufflers-over-x-amount-o) reminds me of a somewhat less ambitious$^1$ question i have been meaning to ask.

suppose 3 people each have a deck of $M$ cards numbered from 1 to $M$, in random order. together, they turn over one card at a time. on any such trial, a match occurs if at least 2 cards show the same number. let $X$ be the number of matches that occur in the $M$ trials. what is the probability distribution of $X$? [for starters, what is ${\rm P}(X=0$)?]

an historical note: the solution for 2 players is well-known; *cf* $ $ [Feller, vol.1,3$^{rd}$ Ed., *p* 107](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471257087):

$\quad {\rm P}(X=0) := p_{0}  = 1 - 1 + \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots \pm \frac{1}{M!}$,

which, for $M$ not too small, is about 1/e. [for $M$ = 10, the two numbers already agree, on rounding, to 5 decimal places.]

more generally,

$\quad {\rm P}(X=k) := p_{k}  = \frac{1}{k!} \\{ 1 - 1 + \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots \pm \frac{1}{(N-k)!}\\} \sim \frac{e^{-1}}{k!}.$

[so as $M \to\infty, X$ tends in law to a poisson variable with mean 1.]

for $k=M-1$ this gives: $p_{M-1} = 0$ [which is obvious]. also, $p_M= \frac{1}{M!}$.

Feller obtains these formulae using the inclusion-exclusion principle.

---

$^1$ in the sense that it involves only 3 people, rather than everyone in the world, and they shuffle their decks only once, rather than repeatedly since the beginning of time.

Comment: What is the statistical motivation for this question?  (It seems like it would be more appropriate to pose it on a math forum.)

Comment: @whuber: i was hoping that some clever chap, such as you, would have some insights about how to approach this. btw - there is a longish list of related problems on the RHS of the screen, to many of which your question could be applied.